# Types have separate declarations of a private property 'handler'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internationalization, ngx-translate

I'm trying to internationalize my angular app. Unfortunately, I get this error message " Types have separate declarations of a private property 'handler'. " I know that there is already a thread about it, but the solution is not working for me, I tried to change dependencies versions, and I still get this error. The problem occurs when I try to create and export a function that reutnrs http.

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
      defaultLanguage: 'en-US',
    }),

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http); => the problem occurs at http.
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue as you are describing. What caused the error was that I was trying to use an external package (as a peer dependency) and it wasn't being added to the main project. Adding that package as a devDependency solved my issue.